# pod install fails on linphone-sdk in Azure Devops Pipeline

Tags: ios, cocoapods, azure-pipelines, xcodebuild, linphone-sdk

After the `6b0a31e4` commit (https://gitlab.linphone.org/BC/public/podspec) my pipeline is fails. Im try to run a simple `pod install`.

The log says: `[!] Couldn't determine repo type for URL:` https://gitlab.linphone.org/BC/public/podspec.git`: (<unknown>): mapping values are not allowed in this context at line 3 column 1`

My Podfile:

```
    # DO NOT MODIFY -- auto-generated by Apache Cordova
    source 'https://cdn.cocoapods.org/'
    source 'https://gitlab.linphone.org/BC/public/podspec.git'
    platform :ios, '11.0'
    use_frameworks!
    post_install do |installer|
      installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
          config.build_settings['EXPANDED_CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY'] = ""
          config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED'] = "NO"
          config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED'] = "NO"
        end
      end
    end
    target '${{ parameters.app }}' do
        project '${{ parameters.app }}.xcodeproj'
        pod 'SVProgressHUD'
        pod 'linphone-sdk', '4.3'
        pod 'MobileVLCKit', '3.3.15'
        pod 'Firebase/Core', '6.33.0'
        pod 'Firebase/Auth', '6.33.0'
        pod 'Firebase/Messaging', '6.33.0'
        pod 'Firebase/Performance', '6.33.0'
        pod 'Firebase/RemoteConfig', '6.33.0'
        pod 'Firebase/InAppMessaging', '6.33.0'
        pod 'FirebaseFirestore', :tag => '6.33.0', :git => 'https://github.com/invertase/firestore-ios-sdk-frameworks.git'
        pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics', '6.33.0'
        pod 'GoogleSignIn', '5.0.2'
        pod 'GoogleTagManager', '7.1.4'
    end
```

It's works on Macbook, only fails on Azure Pipeline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pod setup` before the `pod install` is solved the problem.